why is on_call firebase function returning INTERNAL exception
firebase local emulation side:
initialize_app()

@https_fn.on_call( cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins="*",
        cors_methods=["get", "post", "options"],))
def validateEmail(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> Any :
    return {"text":{"valid:":"true"}}

The android app side.
    val func = Firebase.functions
    private fun validateEmail(str:String): Task<String> {
        val data = hashMapOf(
            "email" to str
        )
        return func.getHttpsCallable("validateEmail").call(data)
            .continueWith()
            {  task ->
                println("RAM_DBG" + task.result?.data.toString())
                task.result?.data as String

            }

    }

    override  fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        func.useEmulator("localhost", 5001)
        validateEmail("something@gmail.com")
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    val e = task.exception
                    if(e is FirebaseFunctionsException)
                    {
                        println("RAM_DBG:" + e.code.toString() + e.details.toString())
                    }
                }
            }


This alwasy gives the FirebaseFunctionsException and code = INTERNAL. what is wrong?
What instrumentation and logging possibilites are there on both sides?
When running using curl like below
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @book.json -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5001/<app>/us-central1/validateEmail
{"result":{"text":{"valid":"true"}}}

Expecting the "valid:":"true" to be returned

The key "valid:" might cause issues because of the colon. Change it to "valid"

It's perfectly valid to have a colon in a JSON object property name.

No reason to downvote. It's valid but not common hence the comment is valid

This isn't right:
func.useEmulator("localhost", 5001)

In the Android emulator, "localhost" refers to the Android emulator virtual machine itself, which is not where your Firebase emulator is running.  Your emulator is running on your development machine, which is referred to as 10.0.2.2 from within in the Android emulator.  See the Android documentation for details:

10.0.2.2  Special alias to your host loopback interface (127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

See also the Firebase emulator documentation:
// 10.0.2.2 is the special IP address to connect to the 'localhost' of
// the host computer from an Android emulator.
val firestore = Firebase.firestore
firestore.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080)

See also:

How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?


Thanks for the responses. Still the same issue. Its not firestore, its functions. Is functions really supported on emulator. Tried 10.0.2.2, also httpsCallableFromURL with the full local URL with 10.0.2.2 as well as the IP assigned by the modem.
for now I am deploying the functions and testing them to move forward.

The emulator requires the same IP address configuration no matter which product you're using.  I copied directly from the documentation so you know which part of it is relevant. You'll need different configurations for each product.
